# Showing that $\int_0^1 \vert 1 - e^{2\pi i z} \vert^{-1} dx \ll \log(2 + y^{-1})$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to modify some work of Henryk Iwaniec involving bounds on the Fourier coefficients of modular forms. There is a bound which he gets that I'm having trouble understanding.

> So I want to show that
>   $$
> \int_0^1 \vert 1 - e^{2\pi i z} \vert^{-1} dx \ll \log(2 + y^{-1})
> $$
>   where $z = x + iy$ and $y > 0$.

When I write $f(y) \ll g(y)$, I mean that there is some $C$ such that $\vert f(y) \vert \leq C g(y)$ for all sufficiently large $y$. That is, it's a Big Oh notation.

Intuitively, a result of this shape is pretty clear. As $y$ gets large, the term $e^{-2\pi y}$ appearing multiplied by $e^{2\pi i x}$, which has the effect of making the denominator look more and more like a constant.

As a more specific reference, this appears in the proof of Theorem 5.3 in his book *Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms*.

Comment: Does it help to that $e^{2 i  \pi z} = 1+\frac{2}{\coth(i \pi z) - 1}$, a function that has periodic real *and* imaginary parts bounded within the range $(-1,1)$? Just  a thought, as this shows that the left side of the equation stays bound. If this helps I'll expand into an answer, if not... best of luck :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first,
$$ \left\|1-e^{2\pi i z}\right\| = \left\|1-e^{-2\pi y}\left(\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)\right) \right\|=\sqrt{(1-e^{-2\pi y})^2+4e^{-2\pi y}\sin^2(\pi x)}$$
hence the integrand function is small if $x$ is not close to the endpoints of $[0,1]$, and can be bounded (by the well-known Taylor series of $\sin(z)$ and $1-e^{-z}$) by something like:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\min(x^2,(1-x)^2)+y^2}}$$
if $x$ is close to endpoints of $[0,1]$. Notice that:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{2\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{\pi}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\right)\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{1}{y}\right).$$

Comment: beautiful solution. I applaud you.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought you might be one to answer. If I might ask a brief ilumination: can you say something about how to see your bound following "and can be bounded by something like..."

Comment: @mixedmath: sure. By well-known Taylor expansions, if $x$ and $y$ are both close to zero, we have $\sin(\pi x)\sim \pi x$ and $1-e^{-2\pi y}\sim 2\pi y$, hence that $\frac{1}{\left\|\ldots\right\|}$ can be upper-bounded by a simpler and easily integrable function.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you. This is very nice and elegant.

Comment: I have one more question. Does this bound also hold if $y$ is very large? This is purely speculative, as it's not necessary for the proof or my application. But in this case, we cannot approximate $e^{-2\pi y}$ by the linear Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @mixedmath: if $y$ is large, we may approximate $(1-e^{-2\pi y})^2$ with $1$, $\sin(\pi x)$ with $\pi x$ and follow exaclty the same lines.